# set jqgrid total page to *Many*

Tags: jqgrid, paging, paginator

I'm using jqgrid in my project. I have huge amount of data which have to be load by paging. 
Is there a way to set total pages of paging to **Many** value.

Comment: What do you mean ? Can you clarify with details ?

Comment: I have huge amount of data, for example 90,000,000 rows in a table.
I have a jqgrid to show this table's data. For this amount of data, total rows of grid is something about 900,000. I don't want show this total page. I want set total page to **many**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jqGrid has `recordtext` option which will be set to default value (something like "View {0} - {1} of {2}") inside of language specific file `grid.locale-XX.js` which you use. If you would use instead the option `recordtext: "View {0} - {1} of many"` the user will see in the pager the modified text. The text in the pager will be displayed only in combination with the option `viewrecords: true`. See [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3apager#definition) for more details.